# Python: file write and iterating re.sub from dict only writes last occurrence

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm unable to figure out how to write and save all re.sub iteration from a dict. Only the last occurrence is saved to the file. I have a translation-worksheet.csv formatted as:

```
locale, lang, Foo-v2, Bar-v2
de_DE, German, German-Foo-v2, German-Bar-v2
zh_CN, Chinese, 零件-Foo-v2, 零件-Bar-v2
```

There's a folder with a file for each language: target/de_DE_v123.xml

The contents of a file:

```
<trans-unit id="14_de_DE" resname="documentGroup.translation">
            <source xml:lang="en-GB">Foo-v2</source>
            <target xml:lang="de-DE">German-Foo-v1</target>
         </trans-unit>      
         <trans-unit id="1759_de_DE" resname="documentGroup.translation">
            <source xml:lang="en-GB">Bar-v2</source>
            <target xml:lang="de-DE">German-Bar-v1</target>
</trans-unit>
```

The goal is to go into each translation file and update all target text. Regex must be used because the target translation text must be over-written regardless of what's currently.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import re

data = pd.read_csv('translate-worksheet.csv', sep=',', header=0)
englishTranslation = data.columns[2:] #get English text
for k, v in data.iterrows():
    locale = v[0]
    docGroup = v[2:]
    findnreplace = dict(zip(englishTranslation,docGroup)) #{english source: translated target}
    print("Working on language:"+locale)
    for propFile in glob.glob('target\\*'+locale+'*.xml'):
        print("  xliff file:"+propFile)
        with open(propFile, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            content = f.read()
            for source, target in findnreplace.items():
                print("   Replacing:"+source+", with:"+target)
                match = re.sub(r'(?<='+source+'<\/source>)[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)\>(.*?)\<',r"\1"+">"+target+"<", content,flags=re.MULTILINE)
                f.seek(0)
                f.write(match)
            print(match)
```

**Expected** output:

```
<trans-unit id="14_de_DE" resname="documentGroup.translation">
   <source xml:lang="en-GB">Foo-v2</source>
   <target xml:lang="de-DE">German-Foo-v2</target>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="1759_de_DE" resname="documentGroup.translation">
   <source xml:lang="en-GB">Bar-v2</source>           
   <target xml:lang="de-DE">German-Bar-v2</target>
 </trans-unit>
```

**Actual** output:

```
<trans-unit id="14_de_DE" resname="documentGroup.translation">
   <source xml:lang="en-GB">Foo-v2</source>
   <target xml:lang="de-DE">German-Foo-v1</target>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit id="1759_de_DE" resname="documentGroup.translation">
    <source xml:lang="en-GB">Bar-v2</source>            <target xml:lang="de-DE">German-Bar-v2</target>
 </trans-unit>
```

I'm new to Python and welcome all critiquing to improve the code overall.

**UPDATE with solution:**
This may probably very inefficient code because it opens the file, modifies it, and closes it each time, but it works and my files are only 15kb each. I changed it from "open the file and for every source and target in the dict, do something" to "for every source and target in the dict, open the file and do something.

```
for propFile in glob.glob('target\\*'+locale+'*.xml'):
        print("  xliff file:"+propFile)
        for source, target in findnreplace.items():
            with open(propFile, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                content = f.read()
                f.seek(0)
                print("   Replacing:"+source+", with:"+target)
                match = re.sub(r'(?<='+source+'<\/source>)[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)\>(.*?)\<',r"\1"+">"+target+"<", content,flags=re.MULTILINE)
                f.write(match)
                f.truncate()
        print(match)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may probably very inefficient code because it opens the file, modifies it, and closes it each time, but it works and my files are only 15kb each. I changed it from "open the file and for every source and target in the dict, do something" to "for every source and target in the dic, open the file and do something.

```
for propFile in glob.glob('target\\*'+locale+'*.xml'):
        print("  xliff file:"+propFile)
        for source, target in findnreplace.items():
            with open(propFile, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                content = f.read()
                f.seek(0)
                print("   Replacing:"+source+", with:"+target)
                match = re.sub(r'(?<='+source+'<\/source>)[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)\>(.*?)\<',r"\1"+">"+target+"<", content,flags=re.MULTILINE)
                f.write(match)
                f.truncate()
        print(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it looks like you want to replace a block of text within an existing text file using regex. For this the basic logic is:

- Find the text you want to replace
- Store the existing file text before this text
- Store the existing file text after this text
- Create the replacement text to be used in the updated file
- Rewrite the file with the 'before' text, the replacement text, and the 'after' text

Without your actual data, I can't confirm this updated code works, but it should be close:

```
for source, target in findnreplace.items():
    print("   Replacing:"+source+", with:"+target)
    # find start\end index of text to be replaced
    srch = re.search(r'(?<='+source+'<\/source>)[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)\>(.*?)\<',r"\1"+">"+target+"<", content,flags=re.MULTILINE)
    startidx, endidx = .span() # position of text within file
    # get replacement text                
    match = re.sub(r'(?<='+source+'<\/source>)[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)\>(.*?)\<',r"\1"+">"+target+"<", content,flags=re.MULTILINE)
    f.seek(0) # from file start
    preblk = f.read(startidx) # all text before replace block
    f.seek(endidx) # end of replace block
    postblk = f.read(endidx)  # all text after replace block
    f.seek(0)  # restart from beginning
    f.truncate(0)  # clear file contents
    f.write(preblk)
    f.write(match)
    f.write(postblk)
print(match)
```

Comment: This didn't work, but it did help me figure out the problem. I realized that I needed a way to save or retain the modified re.sub. Modification explained in the update. Thanks for getting my gears turning. I was absolutely lost.